# Problem with creating animations

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, frames, sigabrt

I'm working with cocos2d 0.99.5. I need to create animations. I have 01.png in my resources and in my project. It's ok. I don't understand why I can't create a frame. I've got error SIGABRT.

```
CCSprite *frame = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"01.png"];
```

I've tried to use this

```
CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]
                        spriteFrameByName:@"01.png"];
```

But I've got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you must have your sprite in the spriteSheet. Here is the tutorial about creating animations: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:animation

Comment: +(id)spriteSheetWithFile:(NSString*)fileImage capacity:(NSUInteger)capacity // XXX DEPRECATED

Comment: Deprecated:
Use CCSpriteBatchNode instead

Comment: i gave you one. Just change CCSpriteSheet to CCSpriteBatchNode. They are the same

Comment: I can't create spriteFrame. (+)spriteWithSpriteFrameName doesn't work